# How exactly do the semantics of the HTML5 <header>, <section>, and <footer> tags work?

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup

I'm a bit puzzled how I'm supposed to use the HTML5 `<header>`, `<section>`, and `<footer>` tags. Currently, I can't work out whether to use them like this:

```
<section id="example_section">
    <header>
        <h1>Example Section</h1>
        <p>etc</p>
    </header>

    <p>Content para 1</p>
    <p>Content para 2</p>
    <p>Content para 3</p>

    <footer>
        Wasn't that swell?
    </footer>
</section>
```

Or like this:

```
<header>
    <h1>Example Section</h1>
    <p>etc</p>
</header>

<section id="example_section">
    <p>Content para 1</p>
    <p>Content para 2</p>
    <p>Content para 3</p>
</section>

<footer>
    Wasn't that swell?
</footer>
```

Or compromising, like this:

```
<section id="example_section_wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Example Section</h1>
        <p>etc</p>
    </header>
    <section id="example_section">
        <p>Content para 1</p>
        <p>Content para 2</p>
        <p>Content para 3</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        Wasn't that swell?
    </footer>
</section>
```

I've included the ID's to show the intended meaning of the sections. I realise that they are unnecessary. Which method is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All are correct in one way another but this is more better then any other

```
<section id="example_section_wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Example Section</h1>
        <p>etc</p>
    </header>
    <section id="example_section">
        <p>Content para 1</p>
        <p>Content para 2</p>
        <p>Content para 3</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        Wasn't that swell?
    </footer>
</section>
```

Couple of best practice and tuts links

- [HTML 5 and CSS 3: The Techniques You’ll Soon Be Using](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html-5-and-css-3-the-techniques-youll-soon-be-using/)
- [HTML5 Overview](http://oshyn.com/_blog/General/post/HTML5_Overview/) (*best practice block)
- [Designing for the Future with HTML5+CSS3 : Tutorials and Best Practices](http://devsnippets.com/article/designing-with-html5-css3.html)

Comment: Is it a good idea to take semantics advice from someone who says "more better then any other"? (**+1**)

Comment: @Eric: See http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/ and http://html5doctor.com/downloads/h5d-sectioning-flowchart.png.

Answer (score 1):

A section can contain a section but a better general container is actuall article. Instead of this:

```
<section id="example_section_wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Example Section</h1>
        <p>etc</p>
    </header>
    <section id="example_section">
        <p>Content para 1</p>
        <p>Content para 2</p>
        <p>Content para 3</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        Wasn't that swell?
    </footer>
</section>
```

You might want to use this:

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h1>Example Section</h1>
        <p>etc</p>
    </header>
    <section id="example_section">
        <p>Content para 1</p>
        <p>Content para 2</p>
        <p>Content para 3</p>
    </section>
    <footer>
        Wasn't that swell?
    </footer>
</article>
```

Like this it feels natural to have various sections in one article.

Comment: better use it this way to standardize the meaning of section and article. +1 to this post.

Answer (score 0):

The tags themselves are pretty abstract, right now. You can use them in any of the ways described above, but your third option is most-correct.

Answer (score 0):

They can all make sense, but the first one is the most correct, in general.

Assuming the whole snippet represents a real section (content about the same topic) it makes sense for it to have a header and a footer inside of the section itself. Also a section needs a heading (h1-6, at least one. Possibly with a hgroup if more than one) and it's missing from your second and third example.